# Databricks Differences between Streaming Tables vs Live Tables vs Streaming Live Tables

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql, delta-live-tables

I am new to Databricks and I would like to understand the differences between a Live Table, Streaming Live table and a Streaming Table, what difference do they have?

1. Do the differences between them arise due to cost or the type of data which is ingested?
2. If I am trying to ingest data from a cloud source, does it matter which type of table I am creating?

Streaming table creation

```
   { CREATE STREAMING TABLE [ IF NOT EXISTS ] }
      table_name
      [ table_specification ]
      [ table_clauses ]
      [ AS query ]
```

Streaming Live table

```
 { CREATE STREAMING LIVE TABLE [ IF NOT EXISTS ] }
  table_name
  [ table_specification ]
  [ table_clauses ]
  [ AS query ]
```

Could someone please explain the differences?

Comment: Can you show a specific example of usage? Are you talking about streaming tables defined via SQL in the SQL warehouses?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have modified the question to differentiate the streaming and streaming live table, I figured a Live table is a DLT pipeline which we create using notebooks